# Extract specific elements from a multidimensional array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, destructuring

I would like to use an *array of indices* of another array to extract the specified elements.

Such that the result is a one dimensional array or results.

Psuedocode that is clearly not quite right:

```swift
let p:[[Double]] = [[3,2],[4,1]]
let t:[[Int]] = [[0,0],[1,0]]
t.map{ (y,x) in p[y][x] } // expecting: [3,4]
```

Comment: Wouldn't an array of tuples be more appropriate for the indices?

Comment: if I were given tuples of indices , I think yes that would be better to work with!

Comment: You may be using the wrong data structure here. `[[Double]]` is not a "2-dimensional array." It's an array of arrays. Those are different things. Every row, for example, can have a different number of elements. It does not behave like a matrix and mutating it tends to be more expensive than expected. If you want a "multi-dimensional array of a fixed size and dimension", in most cases I recommend building it as a custom struct and giving it the interface you want (generally storing the values as a simple one-dimensional Array).

Comment: (The one thing you unfortunately cannot do is define a generic `Matrix<N>` where `N` is an integer and subscripts can be checked for the right length at compile-time. Swift doesn't support that kind of parameterization.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let p:[[Double]] = [[3,2],[4,1]]
let t:[[Int]] = [[0,0],[1,0]]
let res = t.map { p[$0.first!][$0.last!] }  
print(res)
```

Comment: thats great, and works for 2d arrays. is this generalizable though? is there no way to destructure the lambda parameters?

Comment: Could be `let res = t.map { x in p[x.first!][x.last!] }  `

Comment: maybe I wasn't generic enough. I'm marking yours as the answer .. even though now I am wanting something more like `t.map{ coords in elementAtIndex(index: coords, from: p) }`

Comment: @robertotomás: The problem with such a `elementAtIndex(index: coords, from: p)` method is that there are no fixed-sized arrays in Swift, so there is no way for the compiler to check that the “length” of `coords` matches the “dimensionality” of `p`. There might be a solution via `Any` but that would not be nice and you lose  the type safety.

Answer (score 2):

Using tuples for the indices would make your code safer, as tuples can be declared of having a fixed number of elements.

Here's how a possible implementation could look like:

```swift
func extract<T>(indices: [(Int, Int)], from array: [[T]]) -> [T] {
    indices.map { array[$0][$1] }
}

let p: [[Double]] = [[3,2], [4,1]]
let t = [(0,0), (1,0)]
print(extract(indices: t, from: p)) // [3.0, 4.0]
```

Overloads can be added to support 3-D arrays also, or 4-D ones. For example, for 3-D arrays:

```swift
func extract<T>(indices: [(Int, Int, Int)], from array: [[[T]]]) -> [T] {
    indices.map { array[$0][$1][$2] }
}
```

Comment: Ooops, someone doesn't like the answers to this question, both got downvoted

Comment: yea ignore the peanut gallery. :) thanks to you both

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that can extract a dynamic number of elements from an array. To simplify the parameters the indices are given as a single values so they are expected to be given in the correct order. I also use `precondition` to check that the given indices are not to many or to large

```
func extract<Value>(from array: [[Value]], _ indices: Int...) -> [Value] {
    precondition(indices.count <= array.count)

    return indices.enumerated().map {
        let row = array[$0.offset]
        precondition(row.count > $0.element)

        return row[$0.element]
    }
}
```

an alternative to test here is to use optional indices `Int?...` to not extract from all columns and/or return a `[Value?]` when using optional indices or to avoid the precondition logic.